# Nhibernate critieria: getting empty list returned

Tags: c#, nhibernate

have a class structure like so
Permit -> Financial ->ICollection instrumentList
Instrument -> Agency

That is, an instance of Permit contains an instance of Financial
An instance of Financial has a collection of Instrument objects
An instance of Instrument has an Agency

Using NHibernate Critieria, I want to get a list of Permits with Instruments of a certain type of Agency
This code, gets all Permits with Financial info (it may be the case the a Permit does not have Financial info, in which case I don't need it)

```
// get all all Permits with Financial info
var financialCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Financial>()
       .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Permit.Id")); // Permit.Id in Select 

queryCriteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", financialCriteria)); // Permit.Id in Select
```

Then I want to restrict that list to Agency of a types 2 & 3:

```
// then restrict to certain Agency types
var instrumentCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Instrument>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Id")) // Instrument.Id in Select
    .Add(Restrictions.In("Agency", new object[] { 2, 3})); // Where

queryCriteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", instrumentCriteria)); //
```

However, when running with the 2nd chunk of code, I get back an empty list when I know there are 2s and 3s.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I do understand your scenario correclty, then the `instrumentCriteria` returns the list of Instrument **ID**. So with this list we should not limit the `queryCriteria` but the `financialCriteria`. So try this:

```
financialCriteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", instrumentCriteria));
```

Instead of *queryCriteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", instrumentCriteria));*

And the result (projection) of the `instrumentCriteria` should be the owning `Financial` ID:

```
var instrumentCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Instrument>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Financial.Id")) // owner ID
```

EDIT:

In case, that `Instrument` could reference `Financial`, or at least has property `FinancialId`, the syntax returning Permit, filtered by Agency will look like this:

```
var instrumentCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Instrument>()
    // I. Financial as a reference
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Financial.ID")) 
    // II. or just a int property FinancialId
    // .SetProjection(Projections.Property("FinancialId")) 
    .Add(Restrictions.In("Agency.ID", new object[] { 2, 3 })); // Where

var financialCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Financial>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("ID")) // the ID of instrument
    .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("ID", instrumentCriteria));

var queryCriteria = session.CreateCriteria<Permit>()
    .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Financial.ID", financialCriteria));

var result = queryCriteria.List<Permit>();
Assert.IsTrue(result.Any());
```

Comment: So financialCriteria would be like so:  `ICriteria financialCriteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Instrument));
financialCriteria.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id",instrumentCriteria));`  How do I get the financialCriteria into the query?

Comment: Financial.Id cannot be used here because it is not a member of Instrument

Comment: @numberwang, if you have additional code add it to your _question_. Don't append it to someones else's _answer_.

Comment: Instrument has an Agency.  Financial has a Collection of Instruments

Comment: I edited the answer with full query syntax. It is working, but the `FinancialId` must be available on an `Instrument` entity

Comment: Financial.Id is not available in Instrument. However, Permit.Id is. So using your example but using Permit.Id instead of Financial.Id, it works. Thank you, very much.